# Cassandra/Hector: Add a counter on a composite primary key

Tags: cassandra, hector, cql

I've created a table in CQL3 console (no single primary key constituent is unique, together they will be):

```
CREATE TABLE aggregate_logs (
    bpid varchar,
    jid int,
    month int,
    year int,
    value counter,
PRIMARY KEY (bpid, jid, month, year));
```

then been able to update and query by using:

```
UPDATE aggregate_logs SET value = value + 1 WHERE bpid='1' and jid=1 and month=1 and year=2000;
```

This works as expected. I wanted to do the same update in Hector (in Scala):

```
  val aggregateMutator:Mutator[Composite] = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, compositeSerializer)

  val compKey = new Composite()
  compKey.addComponent(bpid, stringSerializer)
  compKey.addComponent(new Integer(jid), intSerializer)
  compKey.addComponent(new Integer(month), intSerializer)
  compKey.addComponent(new Integer(year), intSerializer)

  aggregateMutator.incrementCounter(compKey, LogsAggregateFamily, "value", 1)
```

but I get an error with the message:

```
...HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:String didn't validate.)
```

Running the query direct from hector with:

```
val query = new me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.CqlQuery(keyspace, compositeSerializer, stringSerializer, new IntegerSerializer())
query.setQuery("UPDATE aggregate_logs SET value = value + 1 WHERE 'bpid'=1 and jid=1 and month=1 and year=2000")
query.execute()
```

which gives me the error:

```
 InvalidRequestException(why:line 1:59 mismatched input 'and' expecting EOF)
```

I've not seem any other examples which use a counter under a composite primary key. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible using directly cql (both via CQLSH and C++, at least):

> cqlsh:goh_master> describe table daily_caps;
>    CREATE TABLE daily_caps
>    (   caps_type ascii,   id ascii,   value counter,   PRIMARY KEY
>    (caps_type, id) ) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND   comment='' AND
>    caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND   read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
>    gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND   replicate_on_write='true' AND
>    compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
>    compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
>
> cqlsh:goh_master> update daily_caps set value=value +1 where caps_type='xp' and id ='myid';
>
> cqlsh:goh_master> select * from daily_caps;
>
> caps_type | id   | value
>
> -----------+------+-------
>
> xp | myid |     1

Answer (score 0):

CQL3 and the thrift API are not compatible. So creating a column family with CQL3 and accessing it with Hector or another thrift based client will not work. For more information see:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4377